# How can I create a DataFrame with feature, value and index of not missing data (not NaN's)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following Data Frame

```
data = {'first_set_of_numbers':  [3,9,6,np.nan],
        'second_set_of_numbers': [np.nan,13,np.nan,np.nan]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['first_set_of_numbers','second_set_of_numbers'], index=['A','B','C','D'])
df
```

[image]

How can I now get a new Data Frame that shows all the not missing values with their accoring feature and index? It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [2493]: df.stack().reset_index(level=[1], name='value').rename(columns={'level_1':'feature'})
Out[2493]: 
                 feature  value
A   first_set_of_numbers    3.0
B   first_set_of_numbers    9.0
B  second_set_of_numbers   13.0
C   first_set_of_numbers    6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`df.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) with `ignore_index` parameter set to `False` and use [**`df.dropna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) here.

```
df.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='features', value_name='value').dropna() 
# default values of `var_name` -> 'variable', `value_name`->'value'

                features  value
A   first_set_of_numbers    3.0
B   first_set_of_numbers    9.0
C   first_set_of_numbers    6.0
B  second_set_of_numbers   13.0
```

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thank you. `df.stack` also handles `NaN` you posted a cool answer. +1ed too!